# Three.Js OBJExporter with textures

Tags: three.js, textures

after I load a model with textures in three.js how to export this model to obj-format also with textures. The standard OBJExporter makes no MTL-file for exported model. And I cannot find a way to solve this problem.

I tried to generate a mtl-file in OBJExporter, but in works buggy. Is there any complete solutions

Thank you for any help!